# ASP.NET Sending Email Strategy on a crowded site

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

after reading lots of articles, questions and answers i am a little confused about best mail sending strategy in a crowded web application.

Currently i am sending my mails with SmtpClient which connects to gmail smtp server.

```
_smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
```

which takes lots of time to send emails (long loadings) and blocks user interaction (it takes lets say 1 sec to register member and 4 secs to send welcome email)

As far as i read through web, people use pickup directories to deliver e-mails (correct me if i am wrong) which instantly writes emails to a folder and another application actually sends these emails.

Now i wanted to use SmtpClient with

```
   DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis
```

but microsoft has deprecated smtp server on iis. (again i guess one would need an smtp server to get mails from pickup-directory and send these emails. doesnt make much sense to me. why would u need an smtp server just to send those mails using an another smtp server like gmail?  a simple service wouldn't suffice?)

So there must be other alternatives (programs, services, smtp services? ) to send mails from a directory.

by sending a mail i mean sending it through gmail, xmail etc. the real term is maybe relaying here. i might be wrong here too. do i really need to setup my own smtp server for site mails? or should i just use gmail to do the job? 
(company mails live on gmail)

so i tried to explain my confusions as much as i could. my real question is what is the best strategy to send emails on a crowded asp.net web application?

(which is obviously not sending them directly in code)

Comment: Are you worried about the speed? [Why not do it in the background?](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: yeah speed is my first concern. is it possible an orphan thread to live in an asp.net environment? because request thread will finish it's job before background thread could complete

Comment: reading through your link :), comment before this one is useless now

Comment: Hire a service to send your emails for you.  The more you send, the more likely you are to be blacklisted as a spammer.  Ensuring this doesn't happen is very complex.  There's a highly downvoted question here with a highly upvoted answer that details the pitfalls, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: thanks @Will, i ll look into those services. but currently i need to find a non-paying option to solve this speed problem

Comment: Then batch it in the background.

Comment: yeah i am currently reading about asp.net background tasks. which will probably solve my speed problem. but i guess i need to handle non-sent mails etc. @mason can you answer question with your comment so i can accept it as answer